# Using AJV in Postman seems to ignore nesting/children

Tags: validation, nested, postman, jsonschema, ajv

I'm trying to validate JSON response messages according to schema.
But as soon as an attribute has the type "array" or "object", AJV seems to ignore them and does not see the nested attribute within that object or array.
I started trying to break up the schema into multiple smaller ones so all objects/arrays are covered, but this is a tedious task and I'm hoping I'm just using AJV incorrectly.

**Example schema (simplified):**

```json
    {
      "type": "object",
      "required": [
        "MainThing"
      ],
      "properties": {
        "MainThing": {
          "type": "string",
          "description": "Some kind of string.",
          "example": "This is some kind of string."
        },
        "NestedThing": {
          "type": "object",
          "required": [
            "NestedAttribute"
          ],
          "properties": {
            "NestedAttribute": {
              "type": "String",
              "description": "A nested string.",
              "example": "This is a nested string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

If I change the `NestedAttribute` to an Integer instead of a String, the schema validation in Postman will tell me the response is valid against the schema. While it's not, because the response will contain a `NestedAttribute` which is a String value.

**The following response would be deemed valid, while it's not:**

```json
    {
      "MainThing": "The main thing",
      "NestedThing": {
        "NestedAttribute": 12345
      }
    }
```

**My Postman testcode:**

```js
    var Ajv = require('ajv'),
    ajv = new Ajv({logger: console}),
    schema = JSON.parse(pm.variables.get("THIS_IS_MY_AWESOME_SCHEMA"));
     
    pm.test('My schema is valid', function() {
        var data = pm.response.json();
        pm.expect(ajv.validate(schema, data)).to.be.true;
    });
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you add a concrete example response that is deemed valid but should not be?

Comment: Hey @Byted, thanks so much for the better formatting and sorry for the late response. I added an example response which is deemed valid by AVJ the way I use it now. For my project, I now actually believe I would need to make 2 schema's in this case; one for the MainThing, and one for the NestedThing, just to get the NestedAttribute validated.

Comment: I don't know if it's related, but the schema you provided would fail meta-schema validation. The valid values for `type` are all lower case, and you have `String`. When using ajv (probably not the same version), I get a schema error: https://jsonschema.dev/s/jhtJ3